# Extracting a selection of elements out of array, when elements to select are not consecutive

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I've got some array. Like for example:

```
const ints = [8, 3, 9, 1, 4, 7, 2];
```

I would like to have the elements, let's say index 0, 3 and 4.

Array.slice() works only for a consecutive range of elements.

What I would like to have is basically something like:

```
const extractedElements = ints.extract([0, 3, 4]);
```

**Is there a way to accomplish that operation in JavaScript?**

**Or do I have to extract the elements individual via index-access?**

Comment: can your index array contain indices who do not exist in the data array? what about the order?

Comment: @NinaScholz For the needed purpose: No. I assume that all index are present. And Order matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `map` method for this.

```js
let extractList = [0, 3, 4], ints = [8, 3, 9, 1, 4, 7, 2];
console.log(extractList.map(i => ints[i]));
```

Comment: This is not the best approach because, for each item, the `includes` function could iterate the whole array `extractList`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a array prototype function to implement that custom logic:

```js
Array.prototype.extract = function(indexArr) {
 return indexArr.map(index => this[index]);
};

const ints = [8, 3, 9, 1, 4, 7, 2];
const extractedElements = ints.extract([0, 3, 4]);
console.log(extractedElements);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `map` as follow

```js
let extractList = [0, 3, 4], 
    numbers = [8, 3, 9, 1, 4, 7, 2],
    extract = (i) => numbers[i];
    
console.log(extractList.map(extract));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take `flatMap`, because this take the opportunity to omit non given indices.

This approach omits sparse items and returns only the items who have the same index.

```js
Array.prototype.extract = function(indices) {
    return indices.flatMap(index => index in this ? this[index] : []);
};

const
    ints = [, 3, 9, 1, 4, 7, 2];
    extractedElements = ints.extract([0, 3, 4, 42]);

console.log(extractedElements);
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. The approach, which uses .filter() has worked well for me. But that's great, too.

Answer (score 1):

- `Array.prototype` for pseudoclassical instantiation

  ```
    array.extract()
  ```
- Rest parameter to pass any number off index numbers as an array

  ```
    array.extract(...indexes)
  ```
- `.flatMap()` to filter the return

  ```
    return indexes.flatMap(i =>...
  ```
- and `.slice()` to extract elements at the assigned indexed positions

  ```
    ...this.slice(i, i + 1);
  ```

This only iterates as many times as the length of the `...indexes` parameter rather than the length of the input array (ie `ints`). In the case of the demo below it iterates 3 times rather than 7 times.

---

#### Demo

```js
const ints = [8, 3, 9, 1, 4, 7, 2];

Array.prototype.extract = function(...indexes) {
  return indexes.flatMap(i => this.slice(i, i + 1));
};

console.log(ints.extract(2, 4, 6));
```